# React simple checkbox component - Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: forms, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

I have a simple checkbox component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Checkbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { isChecked: false };

    this.handleCheckboxChange = this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isChecked} onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} />
        Checkbox
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleCheckboxChange(e) {
    this.setState({ isChecked: e.target.checked });
  }
}

export default Checkbox;
```

However, toggling the checkbox produces the following error:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Checkbox
>   component.

Am I missing something when creating controlled components?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle somewhere to repro this? Your Checkbox component code looks ok. It may be an issue with other controls around it.

Comment: yeah, looks fine to me and also works fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXJvwm so you problem is somewhere upper in the chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it was a problem with `react-hot-loader`. Apparently saving the value of `this` doesn't work in the constructor with `react-hot-loader`. The fix is to manually enable the `transform-es2015-classes` plugin in your babelrc. I had this issue previously but it went away so I assumed it was fixed, but it randomly popped up again.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you move the handlecheckbox method outside of the render (inbetween constructor and render)?